# Hide menu items when ActionLayout is opened

Tags: android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, menuitem, actionview

I am using ActionBarSherlock:

There are 3 menu items, of which only 1 has an ActionLayout.

**default_menu.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/searchIcon"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/search_icon_actionview"
    android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:title="Search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/newIcon"
    android:icon="@drawable/new_icon"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:title="New"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/notificationIcon"
    android:icon="@drawable/notification_icon"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:title="Notifications"/>
```

if i am using the above code. Only 1st 2 icons are visible. And if i make 2nd and 3rd as **Always** they remain even when the **actionLayout** is opened when clicked on **Search**.

I want to show all the 3 Menu Items initially and when search_icon is clicked hide every Item.

I also have a doubt about my implementation, whether i am doing i the right way.

**In the Activity's(which has a viewPager) first Fragment:**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.searchIcon:

    mEtSearchbar.clearFocus();
    (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           mEtSearchbar.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0));
           mEtSearchbar.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP , 0, 0, 0));
       }
    }, 100);

        return true;
    case R.id.newIcon:

        return true;
    case R.id.notificationIcon:

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.default_menu, menu);

    mSearchbar = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.searchIcon);
    View actionview = mSearchbar.getActionView();
    mEtSearchbar = ((EditText) actionview.findViewById(R.id.search_editText));
    ImageView searchImage = ((ImageView) actionview.findViewById(R.id.search_image));
    searchImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String s = mEtSearchbar.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "Searching for: " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Comment: @Giuseppe Yes. Check my answer below and ask if you want me to add anything else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what i ended up using.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

            MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

            mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
            setupSearchView(searchItem);

            mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            // hide action item
                            if (menu != null) {
                                    menu.findItem(R.id.notifications).setVisible(false);
                                    menu.findItem(R.id.share).setVisible(false);
                            }

                    }
            });
            mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onClose() {
                            adapter.getFilter().filter("");
                            // re-show the action button
                            if (menu != null) {
                                    menu.findItem(R.id.notifications).setVisible(true);
                                    menu.findItem(R.id.share).setVisible(true);
                            }
                            return false;

                    }
            });
            return true;
    }

private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {
         //code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I already tried this, but unfortunately the setOnCloseListener() doesn't work! It doesn't do anything, it doesn't enter in onClose(), sigh. Perhaps is it a bug in actionbarsherlock?

Comment: On which Android version have you tested it? Does it work on Android >= 4 ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could set something like this on the searchView :

```
searchCommand.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
```

Comment: That's the only correct answer. All other answers are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks.. Works for me

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but try this once.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu);
for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
    MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_more) {
        itemChooser = item.getActionView();
        if (itemChooser != null) {
            itemChooser.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }
}
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```